# "State objects" for EF code first mapping - hiding completely?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, domain-driven-design, dao

After having a good week of pure frustration that resulted from numerous attempts to map one of my aggregates using EF Code First without turning it into a complete anemic domain model, I recently stumbled upon [this blog entry](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=879) from Vaughn Vernon describing a beautiful solution that doesn't involve ridiculous mapping attempts, 'DAOs' etc., but clean domain entities and **state objects** which let EF perfectly do it's job.

Now, the solution has one minor flaw, which I'd like to know if there's any way to get rid of it: In order to "hide" the **state** objects from a client (and let them be only accessible for EF), Vaughn denoted the "State" accessor as well as the "State constructor" as internal. This works fine when everything is pushed together into a single library project only accessible from the outside, however in most cases the domain is spread across multiple modules etc, which means I have to expose the members as public - thus exposing technical concerns in a domain entity to clients (which they could use.. or misuse).

Is there a possibility to hide the *state objects* from client access?

Answer (score 1):

You could either...

a) add the [`[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("FriendAssemblyName")]` assembly attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to your `AssemblyInfo.cs`, as long as you know all your friend assemblies, or

b) use [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) to hide the property from users that don't cast your object to a dedicated interface, e.g. `IState<T>`, or

c) add the [`[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to hide the properties from IntelliSense.